# Are all these if-statements really necessary?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have this function that connects two rooms with a hallway. It seems really inefficient but I can't find a better way to do it. It is part of my BSP algorithm for generating dungeons. You can find the full algorithm [here](https://github.com/TheMechanicX32/BSP-Swift-dungeon-Generator).

```
public func createHall(left:Room, right:Room) {
    // Connects 2 rooms together with hallways

    // Reset hallways function to make sure its empty. hallways = [Room]()
    hallways = []

    // get width and height of first room
    let point1 = CGPoint(x: Int.random(in: (left.x1 + 1)..<(left.x2 - 1)),
                         y: Int.random(in: (left.y1 + 1)..<(left.y2 - 1)))

    // get width and height of second room
    let point2 = CGPoint(x: Int.random(in: (right.x1 + 1)..<(right.x2 - 1)),
                         y: Int.random(in: (right.y1 + 1)..<(right.y2 - 1)))

    let w = point2.x - point1.x
    let h = point2.y - point1.y

    if w < 0 {
        if h < 0 {
            if Double.random(in: 0..<1.0) > 0.5 {
                hallways.append(Room(X: Int(point2.x), Y: Int(point1.y), W: Int(abs(w)), H: 1))
                hallways.append(Room(X: Int(point2.x), Y: Int(point2.y), W: 1, H: Int(abs(h))))
            } else {
                hallways.append(Room(X: Int(point2.x), Y: Int(point2.y), W: Int(abs(w)), H: 1))
                hallways.append(Room(X: Int(point1.x), Y: Int(point2.y), W: 1, H: Int(abs(h))))
            }
        } else if h > 0 {
            if Double.random(in: 0..<1.0) > 0.5 {
                hallways.append(Room(X: Int(point2.x), Y: Int(point1.y), W: Int(abs(w)), H: 1))
                hallways.append(Room(X: Int(point2.x), Y: Int(point1.y), W: 1, H: Int(abs(h))))
            } else {
                hallways.append(Room(X: Int(point2.x), Y: Int(point2.y), W: Int(abs(w)), H: 1))
                hallways.append(Room(X: Int(point1.x), Y: Int(point1.y), W: 1, H: Int(abs(h))))
            }
        } else {
            hallways.append(Room(X: Int(point2.x), Y: Int(point2.y), W: Int(abs(w)), H: 1))
        }
    } else if w > 0 {
        if h < 0 {
            if Double.random(in: 0..<1.0) > 0.5 {
                hallways.append(Room(X: Int(point1.x), Y: Int(point2.y), W: Int(abs(w)), H: 1))
                hallways.append(Room(X: Int(point1.x), Y: Int(point2.y), W: 1, H: Int(abs(h))))
            } else {
                hallways.append(Room(X: Int(point1.x), Y: Int(point1.y), W: Int(abs(w)), H: 1))
                hallways.append(Room(X: Int(point2.x), Y: Int(point2.y), W: 1, H: Int(abs(h))))
            }
        } else if h > 0 {
            if Double.random(in: 0..<1.0) > 0.5 {
                hallways.append(Room(X: Int(point1.x), Y: Int(point1.y), W: Int(abs(w)), H: 1))
                hallways.append(Room(X: Int(point2.x), Y: Int(point1.y), W: 1, H: Int(abs(h))))
            } else {
                hallways.append(Room(X: Int(point1.x), Y: Int(point2.y), W: Int(abs(w)), H: 1))
                hallways.append(Room(X: Int(point1.x), Y: Int(point1.y), W: 1, H: Int(abs(h))))
            }
        } else {
            hallways.append(Room(X: Int(point1.x), Y: Int(point1.y), W: Int(abs(w)), H: 1))
        }
    } else {
        if h < 0 {
            hallways.append(Room(X: Int(point2.x), Y: Int(point2.y), W: 1, H: Int(abs(h))))
        } else if h > 0 {
            hallways.append(Room(X: Int(point1.x), Y: Int(point1.y), W: 1, H: Int(abs(h))))
        }
    }
}
```

Where Room is a custom class I wrote to calculate a rectangle and its
center:

```
class Room {
    var x1:Int
    var x2:Int
    var y1:Int
    var y2:Int
    var center:CGPoint

    init(X: Int, Y: Int, W: Int, H: Int) {
        x1 = X
        x2 = X + W
        y1 = Y
        y2 = Y + H
        center = CGPoint(x: (x1 + x2) / 2, y: (y1 + y2) / 2)
    }
}
```

My most successful attempt:

```
func hCorridor(x1: Int, x2: Int, y: Int) {
    for x in min(x1,x2)...max(x1,x2) {
        hallways.append(Room(X: y, Y: y, W: 1, H: Int(abs(h))))
    }
}

func vCorridor(y1: Int, y2: Int, x: Int) {
    for y in min(y1,y2)...max(y1,y2) {
        hallways.append(Room(X: y, Y: y, W: Int(abs(w), H: 1))
    }
}

// Randomly choose to start with horizontal or vertical corridors
if Double.random(in: 0..<1.0) > 0.5 {
    hCorridor(x1: Int(point1.x), x2: Int(point2.x), y: Int(point1.y))
    vCorridor(y1: Int(point1.y), y2: Int(point2.y), x: Int(point2.x))
} else {
    vCorridor(y1: Int(point1.y), y2: Int(point2.y), x: Int(point1.x))
    hCorridor(x1: Int(point1.x), x2: Int(point2.x), y: Int(point2.y))
}
```

Are all those if-statements in the `createHall()` function really necessary? If not, what would be a better way to write them? All my attempts don't work quite like the if-statements. My attempts give me dead-ends and rooms that are unaccessible.

Comment: Btw, `Double.random(in: 0..<1.0) > 0.5` is complicated way to say `Bool.random()`

Comment: Its a BSP algorithm. It takes two "leaves" and draws a hallway between them. Its not important to the question so I didn't include it.

Comment: I cannot find any symmetry in your if-else branches which is strange. I would suppose that `w > 0` and `w < 0` cases to be similar.

Comment: The if-else structure tests for all possible hallway configurations. I was just curious if there was another way to do it. The if-else statements don't even function properly. They don't generate hallways that are only 1 tile wide/tall. I get really large hallways.

Comment: Unrelated to your current problem, but consider to make `Room` a `struct` (value types are preferred unless you explicitly need the reference type semantics).

Comment: @MartinR It is not only preferred, but also more effeceint if used carefully, it is put on the stack, not on heap, heap allocations on Swift is very slow like C++, not like Java because there is no preallocation and no GC.  So using Structs may make your code faster if you used it correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you

- first choose two random points `point1`, `point2`  in the left (resp. right)
  room, and
- then connect the rooms with two “corridors” from `point1` to `point2`,
  either going horizontally first and then vertically, or vice versa.

Apart from the random choice you don't need if-statements if you use 
`min` and `abs` to compute the corridor coordinates.
Something like (more explanations inline):

```
if Bool.random() {
    // Horizontally first, then vertically:
    // From point1 to (point2.x, point1.y):
    hallways.append(Room(X: Int(min(point1.x, point2.x)), Y: Int(point1.y),
                         W: Int(abs(point1.x - point2.x)), H: 1))
    // From (point2.x, point1.y) to point2:
    hallways.append(Room(X: Int(point2.x), Y: Int(min(point1.y, point2.y)),
                         W: 1, H: Int(abs(point1.y - point2.y))))
} else {
    // Vertically first, then Horizontally:
    // From point1 to (point1.x, point2.y):
    hallways.append(Room(X: Int(point1.x), Y: Int(min(point1.y, point2.y)),
                         W: 1, H: Int(abs(point1.y - point2.y))))
    // From (point1.x, point2.y) to point2:
    hallways.append(Room(X: Int(min(point1.x, point2.x)), Y: Int(point2.y),
                         W: Int(abs(point1.x - point2.x)), H: 1))
}
```

Comment: You might also consider to work with either `Int` or `CGFloat` coordinates only, to avoid all the conversions.

Comment: The conversions do slow down the code, but the `Room` class has to have Ints in the initializer because it makes my job way easier in other parts of the algorithm. It also removes a ton more conversions. Also, I tried this code and it works 100% like the if-statements, but the if-statements don't function like I want them to so I have to do some debugging to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @E.Huckabee: Yes, but you could use integer coordinates for point1, point2.

Comment: How? I need to access the X and Y values of my `Room` class via a CGPoint.

Comment: @E.Huckabee: Why do you have to use CGPoint? Define your own `struct Point` with two integer coordinates and use that.

Comment: Got it. I did what you said and it stopped a lot of conversions. The engine compiles noticeably quicker now.